# Class methods/instance methods in Python

Tags: python

I come from Ruby and I'm getting used to the "explicit over implicit" philosophy that Python follows, but I was confused earlier about how I actually make class methods. Now, I want verification that I am indeed correct in the following:

Every method in a class is essentially a class method in Python.

For example:

```
class Employee(object):

    employeeCount = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        employeeCount += 1

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_employee_count():
        return employeeCount
```

If I understand this correct, for instance `david = Employee("david")` the following two are equivalent:

`david.get_name()` and `Employee.get_name(david)`. Likewise, it makes sense that we could say `get_employee_count` is a class method too, but it doesn't rely on any instance, hence why we don't pass in an instance. This is why it doesn't make sense to type `david.get_employee_count()`, because this would be `Employee.get_employee_count(david)`, but `get_employee_count` doesn't take in a parameter, namely the instance. This concludes that we would just type `Employee.get_employee_count()`.

Am I correct in my thinking? Thank you.

Comment: try actually running the code you pasted. it's not gonna work

Comment: `get_employee_count()` is a not a class method, it's a normal function inside a class.(or static method in py2.x, if used with @staticmethod)

Comment: More specifically, `e = Employee("David"); print e.get_employee_count()` won't work because `get_employee_count` doesn't know where `employeeCount` is

Comment: @hcwhsa: It is still a method when accessed, but is missing the required `self` parameter, so that'll raise an exception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not in py3.x, if called as `Employee.get_employee_count()`.

Comment: I thought employeeCount is a member variable, so it is accessible in all methods in my class?

Comment: @David Specify python version.

Comment: @hcwhsa: Go try that out. `ClassObject.name` returns the function, yes. But `instance.name` invokes the descriptor protocol and without a decorator, that'll return a bound method. And bound methods *require* a first argument to work.

Comment: @hcwhsa: I get the same error (`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'employeeCount' referenced before assignment`) for Python 2.6.7, 2.7.3, and 3.3.0. ETA: Unless you were talking to the OP, and not to me.

Comment: Right now, I'm going through Codecademy Python classes and it works in their editor.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I fixed that error before running the code. Yes I was talking to the OP, your comment is correct. :-)

Comment: Ah, I see I get an error that employeeCount was referenced before assignment. Interesting.

Comment: When you do not pass the `self` argument it is only a normal function, not a `method`. If you want this act just as a method class you can use a decorator `@staticmethod` so you can access it through `Employee.get_employee_count()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not quite right. For something to be a class method rather than an instance method, you have to use the `classmethod` decorator. And that method still takes a parameter, but that param is the class, not the instance. So:

```
@classmethod
def get_employee_count(cls):
    return cls.employeeCount
```

Classes don't actually define a block scope inside them in Python, so just referring to `employeeCount` in the method wouldn't work - that's why the `cls` param is used.

For clarification, a decorator is simply a wrapper around a function - it could also be written

```
def _get_employee_count(cls):
    return cls.employeeCount
get_employee_count = classmethod(_get_employee_count)
```

and `classmethod` is a built-in function.

Also note, in Python (as I thought in Ruby too) we wouldn't normally write accessors for simple variables like `name`, we'd just access them directly.

Comment: Interesting. Then, in my example, what exactly would you call `get_employee_count()`?

Comment: Furthermore, how would I create a class variable in Python? Evidently, `employeeCount = 0` would generate an error.

Comment: Nothing, because it doesn't work: you'd get "TypeError: unbound method get_employee_count() must be called with Employee instance as first argument (got nothing instead)" in Python 3, and "global name 'employeeCount' is not defined" in Python 2.

Comment: No, defining it that way is fine, that doesn't give an error. It's accessing it inside a method that will give an error.

Comment: How would I access it in a method then? Is your way of making a class method going to have cls.employeeCount point to `employeeCount`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does.

Comment: I get an error though, in my initialize method when I try to increment the employeeCount. How would I get past that?

Comment: Further, it seems I could do david.employeeCount, and it will still be seen, but that doesn't seem to make any sense. Will this always be a side-effect? (sorry for all the questions) –

Comment: You can access it through the instance, but if you modify it in any way (eg `david.employeeCount += 1` you'll actually create an instance attribute that shadows the class one, and the changes won't reflect in the class variable. In `__init__`, you'll need to explicitly access the class: `self.__class__.employeeCount += 1` should work.

Comment: You can also use `type(self).employeeCount` instead of `self.__class__.employeeCount`

Answer (score 0):

True. Functions that deal with objects' instances should have `self` in its parameters. Otherwise, they are considered class methods.

*EDIT*

*Class methods* doesn't mean *static methods*! They're not static methods unless you add the decorator `@staticmethod` before the `def`inition of the class function

Comment: No, they are not. You need to use the `@classmethod` decorator to make class methods.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have not heard of decorators in Python. Is it just used for labeling purposes?

Comment: @David Decorators are snippets of code that sets special attributes for the code. *EDIT* More info is [here][1]

  [1]:https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators